# Calling classes from inside classes

Tags: java

I am relatively new to Java and i am trying to solve this particular problem and have come only this far into the solution.

The problem statement is below:

A well renowned hotel has three branches in miami. Namely x,y and z(Actually they gave names).Each has two types of customers. Regular and Rewardee. Also each branch has its own ratings x is given a 3 star rating while y has 5 star rating and z has 4 star rating.

Each hotel has specific rates for weekend and weekdays. x charges $100 for regular customers on weekdays and $120 on weekends While it is $90 for rewardee on weekdays and $60 on weekends. Similarly y charges $130 for regular customers on weekdays and $150 on weekends. While its $100 for rewardee on weekdays and $95 on weekends. While z charges $195 for regular customers on weekdays and $150 on weekends. While its $120 for rewardee on weekdays and $90 on weekends. Now when the customer requests for a particular detail you need to find which hotel would yield the customer profit. In case of tie between hotels compare the ratings and provide the result.

Input format:

regular: 16Mar2010(sun), 19Mar2010(wed), 21Mar2010(Fri)

```
class Hotel {
    private int ratings;

    public int getRating() {
        return ratings;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating) {
        ratings = rating;
    }
}

class Customer extends Hotel {
    private String regular;
    private String rewardee;

    public String getRewardee() {
        return rewardee;
    }

    public void setRewardee(String rewardee) {
        this.rewardee = rewardee;
    }

    public String getRegular() {
        return regular;
    }

    public void setRegular(String regular) {
        this.regular = regular;
    }
}

class Pricing extends Customer {
    private double weekends;
    private double weekdays;

    public double getWeekends() {
        return weekends;
    }

    public void setWeekends(double weekends) {
        this.weekends = weekends;
    }

    public double getWeekdays() {
        return weekdays;
    }

    public void setWeekdays(double weekdays) {
        this.weekdays = weekdays;
    }
}


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pricing x = new Pricing();
        x.setRating(3);
        x.setWeekdays(100);
        x.setWeekends(120);
        Hotel y = new Hotel();
        y.setRating(5);
        Hotel z = new Hotel();
        z.setRating(4);
    }
}
```

I am really struggling to get forward from here, am i going in right direction? How to further go into solving the problem. Please help and also if possible can you refer any good books to build my skills.

Further i am thinking to call classes within other classes to hook up the different classes together. Is that approach good.

Thanks

**P.S Its not Homework.**

Comment: But it looks like Homework

Comment: No, just help me a little on how to get it further or any code changes .

Comment: `Customer extends Hotel` - this alone tells me that you're on the wrong track. "extends" is supposed to be interpreted as "is a". So you're saying "A customer is a hotel". You need to come up with a better OO design.

Comment: Can you please say me how to put objects to communicate with each other.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to achieve, as you don't say so. First the keyword **extends** is for inheritance. Like you have a vehicle superclass and then a car as a special sub class. What you are doing there looks more like you want a hotel to have a price. So you would say that the Hotel object has a Price object - simply by declaring it as a "variable" of Hotel.

Comment: This is all wrong. Go through your code, and when you see "extends" replace it with "is a type of" and you will see that this simply can't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hotel "has a" rating and two pricing schemas - one for regular customers, one for rewardees:

```
class Hotel {
    int rating;
    PricingSchema forRegulars, forRewardees;
}
```

Pricing schema has two prices: weekend and normal:

```
class PricingSchema {
    double weekendPrice, weekdayPrice;
}
```

A customer is or is not a rewardee:

```
class Customer {
    boolean isRewardee;
}
```

A challenge: calculate the the price at a given hotel for for the given day of week for the given customer:

```
hotel.price(customer, dayOfWeek);
```

Now see where this takes you.

Answer (score 1):

You are currently using a *is a* relation. You're declaring that a Pricing *is a* Customer and a Customer *is a* hotel. What you should be thinking about is a *has a* relation. You should declare an instance of a Customer in "Hotel" `private Customer regular` or `private Customer rewardee` and likewise for your Pricing.

Answer (score 0):

> I am really struggling to get forward from here, am i going in right direction?

No, you are not. I am quite sure a `Customer` is *not* a `Hotel`, neither should a `Pricing` be a `Customer`. You are misusing inheritance where the objects should rather just be in relation to each other.

Comment: Thats exactly what i need, how to put objects in relation with each other?

Comment: Exactly as you have done for a string: private String regular;

Comment: private Pricing pricing; <- which say: This thing here has a Pricing object which I name pricing. It is only used within this object (private). You may have to initialize pricing in your parent objects constructor.

Answer (score 0):

i'm no expert myself, but would suggest you rethink the design. Pricing isn't really state that belongs to customers, it belongs to Hotels. My first thought would be to have the Hotel class hold rating and the various prices(Weekend/Weekday for Regular/Reward). These will then belong to each Hotel object.

A seperate customer class(not related) could hold a boolean value for Regular/Reward that you could feed into a getPricing method in the Hotel class. Possibly name,address etc could also live there too in time.

You could then compare the Hotel objects in your main. With what you are currently trying to do i don't think you need to be extending any classes anywhere just yet. If the pricing structure starts to sprawl you might consider keeping that in another class but that's down the line i guess.